# multiple rotations on the same character

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, character, transform

I have a character that rotates in the direction of movement

```
var rot = (x, y, z); //motion vector
 rot.y = 0f;
 var movementRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(rot);
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, movementRot, Time.deltaTime * speedRot);}
```

I would like to rotate its Y axis of rotation, even with the mouse's X axis

```
 loat r = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
    float Xrot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * speedRotation;
    transform.Rotate(0, Xrot, 0);
```

The methods work alone but together they do not.
I have already tried converting transform.Rotate into a quaternion to multiply:

```
var Xrotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, Xrot, 0f);
transform.rotation = Xrotation * movementRot;
```

The result is a character that does not rotate on itself (it is withheld when it tries).
I tried the inverse and converted the quaternion into degrees to add to transform. Rotate. But it didn't help:

```
float angle = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, movementRot)//The result is perfect is on its own on transform.Rotate it works

transform.Rotate(0,f angle + Xrot, 0f); //Together, however, the character rotates at times and turns, on itself only to one side
```

Does anyone know how to do..? (or if it's a possible thing to do xd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got, you want to have two rotation layers - first, you character looks in direction of movement. Then, you can add rotation from your mouse input. Is it right?

If so, first thing what I can recommend - is to split your character into two objects. Parent transform will follow your movement. Then, it's child, will change it's local rotation according to mouse input.

For follow-course rotation, IMHO, the best way is to deal with vectors, instead of quaternions:

```
transform.forward = movementVector;
```

If you need more smooth following, you can do like this:

```
float rotationSpeed = 0.5f;
        transform.forward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, movementVector, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

or

```
float rotationSpeed = 1f;
transform.forward = Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, movementVector, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Then you can apply rotation to child object, like you did (only change - apply as local rotation).

If this kind of rig not an option for you, you need to combine two rotations. For this, again, deal with vector. After applying movement-follow rotation, as described above, add something like this:

```
float Xrot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * speedRotation;
transform.forward += transform.right * Xrot * Time.deltaTime;
```

Note two things:

- In this case, `speedRotation`, probably, must be a lot smaller. You can even multiply it by 0.1f.
- `transform.right` and `transform.forward` can be different for your character, maybe, you need to use `transform.up`, or `-transform.forward`. See at your local transform axes.

Comment: Let me explain. I'm trying to create third-person movements without relying on the camera (the camera must follow the character). Consequently, in addition to the normal rotation in the direction in which it walks, I have to insert the rotation with the mouse (to rotate the character in the direction in which I want, otherwise it can only move forward, backward, right and left without rotating).

Comment: Sorry for such a delay. So why you can't use a "rig" approach? Create your camera, which follows your character's movement. Then, remove camera from it's game object - let it be just a dummy. And put your actual camera as a child of this dummy. And then, apply your mouse-driven rotation to this child camera, not as a `transform.rotation`, but as a `transform.localRotation` instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly, unfortunately your solution does not work for me because when my character walks horizontally, the camera must not be behind it but frame the character walking sideways. The camera should only rotate and stand behind when I walk and rotate vertically.Or at best I would like a solution in which the lateral walk is framed. But I'm not sure which method is used. https://youtu.be/ktXOV_kf6rU?t=4304

Comment: In any case, at the moment to rotate my character I am directing the movement of this with that of a cube placed next to him.
With the mouse the cube rotates and consequently the horizontal and vertical axis move around the world. My character that rotates towards the direction of travel, when he walks, if I use the mouse, it will rotate because it goes towards the axes of the cube that rotate. The camera is set with the rotation of the cube but rotates at a slower speed than the character, so the effect is as if the character follows it.

Comment: A complicated solution, do you find it useful ..? if yours is simpler I would like to use it.

Comment: If you have a solution, which already works for you, definitely, leave it as is, until it works :)